# swagger-java and OpenAPI 3.0 support in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, swagger, openapi

I can't find any place saying which versions of Swagger does camel produce, but using it produces 2.0, is there a configuration that makes it produce 3.0?

Does it even support OpenAPI 3.0? Is it planned?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer after all this time.
This was supported and released in version 2.21.0, according to this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11908

Comment: There is another ticket tracking this change
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12619 which is still open

Answer (score 0):

The camel-swagger-java component does **not** support OpenAPI spec 3

Comment: Yes that's what the description of the issue says, that it doesn't support 3.0 and the issue is to fix it (see title: ... to support OpenAPI Spec 3 ...) and it's resolved in 2.21.0